# Equivalent of Pandas iloc function in dplyr

Tags: r, pandas, dplyr

I'm just trying to crop off rows at the top and bottom of a data frame in dplyr but can't work out to do it.

In Pandas I would use something like iloc just to crop the rows, but can't work out how to do it with dplyr:

This was my suggestion, but it doesn't return a result in R Studio:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(column)) %>% 
  filter(column, between(row_number(), 1, (length(df) - 3))
```

Comment: Maybe look into base R functions `head` and `tail`. For example `tail(head(df, 1), 1)` will drop the first and last rows of a data.frame df.

Comment: @lmo i think you mean -1 in both cases

Comment: Ah, that's great. I just added head(length(df) -14) to the pipe instead of the last line.

Comment: @elksie5000, beware that the length of a data.frame is the number of columns, not rows

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes. Thanks. @elsksie5000, as docendodiscimus's correction notes, you can just use `head(df, -14)`. I meant to add the negatives, but didn't.

Comment: I appreciate the help from both of you. I guess R will just click for me in time.

Comment: also check out `slice` (selects rows by index). In your case `... %>% slice(1:(n() - 3))` (`n()` gives the number of rows). To select the columns you'll need a separate call to `select()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know I'm 6 mo late on this but for anyone looking in the future -- You can use `slice` to cut up a dataframe by index position like iloc. you can use nrow(.) to call out the number of rows in the dataframe. If you want to *remove* off the top 6 and bottom 6, you could do..

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100)

df %>%
  slice(-c(1:6, (nrow(.)-5):nrow(.)))
```

or to *keep* all the rows in-between the 7th position and the 7th to last position, you would do

```
df %>%
   slice(7:(nrow(.)-6))
```

Hope this helps!